# Should .net framework and .net core/.net 5+ have different .gitignore files?

Tags: .net, .net-core, gitignore

I'm migrating one of `.net 4.5` projects to from `svn` to `git` and as far as I can tell `svn` configuration does not ignore any files. Usally I'm generating `.gitignore` files by unsing `dotnet new gitignore` or one templates by [github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore) or [gitignore.io](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore), but it seems like all of those are `.net core`/`.net5+` specific.

Should the `.gitignore` files be different for `.net framework` and later versions of `.net`? If so where can I find an (preferably official) example of `.gitignore` for `.net framework`?

Comment: No, only the section commented with "# .NET Core" is specific to the later versions.

Comment: You can generate the .gitignore file [here](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore)  based on your needs and they may be the same for both versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they might the same.

You can start with this template https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore